# Output for overall MPG is fractionally off (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, c

I created a program where you input the miles driven and the gallons used for each tankful, and the program displays the mpg for each tankful.  I am using Visual Studio 2010.  When I enter the sentinel value of -1, I am given the overall mpg.  Here is my code:

```
/* Name
Lab 3 - Page 105, 3.16
September 23th, 2015
Page 2 of 3 */

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// function main begins program execution
int main( void )
{   
    // initialization phase
    unsigned int counter = 0; // number of tanks used
    float gallons = 0; // gallons
    float miles = 0; // miles
    float milesPerGallon = 0; // MPG
    float allTankMPG = 0; // sum of all tanks (MPGs)

    float averageMPG = 0; // average MPG of all tankfuls

    // processing phase
    // get first tankful information
    printf( "%s", "Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): " ); // prompt for gallons used
    scanf( "%f", &gallons ); // read gallons input from user

    // loop while sentinel value not yet read from user
    while ( gallons != -1 ) {

        printf( "%s", "Enter the miles driven: " ); // prompt for miles driven
        scanf( "%f", &miles ); // read miles input from user

        milesPerGallon = miles / gallons; // miles per gallon for the tank
        printf("%s%.6f\n\n", "The miles/gallon for this tank was: ", milesPerGallon ); // display milesPerGallon
        counter = counter + 1; // increment counter
        allTankMPG = allTankMPG + milesPerGallon; // add the miles per gallon the sum total of every tank's mpg

        // get next tankful information
        printf( "%s", "Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): " ); // prompt for gallons used
        scanf( "%f", &gallons ); // read input of the next gallon from user
    } // end while

    // termination phase
    // if user entered at least one set of information for one tankful
    if ( counter != 0 ) {

        // calculate average MPG of all tankfuls
        averageMPG = (float) allTankMPG / counter; // avoid truncation

        // display average with six digits of precision
        printf( "\n%s%.6f\n\n", "The overall average miles per gallon was ", averageMPG );
    } // end if

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
} // end function main``
```

My output, however looks like this:

- Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 12.8
- Enter the miles driven: 287
- The miles/gallon for this tank was: 22.421875
- Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 10.3
- Enter the miles driven: 200
- The miles/gallon for this tank was: 19.417475
- Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): 5
- Enter the miles driven: 120
- The miles/gallon for this tank was: 24.000000
- Enter the gallons used (-1 to end): -1

The overall average miles per gallon was 21.946449

Press any key to continue . . .

Now according to the book, the overall average MPG should be 21.601423, not 21.946449 when the same exact input is entered.  Can anyone please elaborate on why my output is fractionally off?  Thank you, it is much appreciated.

Comment: If this is C, remove C++ header and remove C++ tag. If it is C++, remove C tag. These are different languages!

Comment: Did you verify the calculation yourself? For example using a calculator or spreadsheet?

Comment: @Olaf: the problem is the same for C and for C++, so it applies to both languages.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: And also for Java, Python and many other languages. Are you supposing to add all these tags, too?

Comment: Since, from the code that was posted, it is impossible to tell whether it is C or C++, and the problem is equally applicable to both languages, *why should it matter* which of these is meant? It is not Java, Python or C#, that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

The book wants you to calculate the average miles per gallon over the entire trip, not the equally-weighted average of the legs irrespective of their length.  For that, keep a sum of total miles and a sum of total gallons.

By the way, it’s a good idea to do your calculations in double precision, even when you’re storing in a float.  This minimizes round-off error.